# How can I filter entities in JHipster using the 'LIKE' operator? It seems that JHipster does not natively support the 'LIKE' operator

Tags: java, spring-boot, jhipster

JHipster Entity filtering itself has limitations, It seems that does not provide support 'LIKE' operator. It only supports 'equal,' 'notEqual,' 'contains,' 'does not contain,' 'exist,' and 'does not exist' operations.How we can support like operator is there any way.Any suggestion will be helpful,
Thank you

Comment: Can you provide any [mcve]?

Comment: You're right, so either you modify the generator and contribute to the project or you code it manually in your project.

Comment: What like pattern do you want to use?